# Authenticate to a machine not in the domain

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-authentication, workgroup

I set up a windows server 2003 in a VM to test some code. The prod server has IIS6 and since I have Win 7 I can only install IIS 7 in my dev machine.

Obviously I didn't add the machine to my company domain, nor that I want to. I'm having troubles authenticating to the machine from the browser in my machine using users created on the VM server.

I've tried

```
<machine_name>\<username>
<workgroup_name>\<username>
<user_name>
<ip_address>\<username>
```

I've run out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

If you use the prefix ".\" in front of the user name, it will change the logon domain to that of the local machine.

i.e. .\username on the computer **MyComputer** is logging in as MyComputer\username.

Comment: I had no success with that either

Comment: Are you using the correct local account for this?